# Rails: where does the infamous "current_user" come from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been looking around recently into Rails and notice that there are a lot of references to `current_user`. Does this only come from Devise? and do I have to manually define it myself even if I use Devise? Are there prerequisites to using `current_user` (like the existence of sessions, users, etc)?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

It is defined by several gems, e.g. Devise

You'll need to store the user_id somewhere, usually in the session after logging in. It also assumes your app has and needs users, authentication, etc.

Typically, it's something like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def current_user
    return unless session[:user_id]
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
  end
end
```

This assumes that the User class exists, e.g. `#{Rails.root}/app/models/user.rb`.

Updated: avoid additional database queries when there is no current user.

Comment: is sessions sort of like a commonly used controller/model for the purpose of controlling a users login status? or is it built into rails?

Comment: `session` is built into Rails. By default, it uses a cookie to maintain a client's state between requests. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sessions for more info.

Comment: NOTE: If you're reading this answer, be sure to include `return unless session[:user_id]` as shown in Zach's answer -- without that, every `if current_user` check while signed out will trigger another database query.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, `current_user` uses `session`. You can do something similar in your application controller if you want to roll your own authentication:

```
def current_user
  return unless session[:user_id]
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
end
```

Comment: is sessions sort of like a commonly used controller/model for the purpose of controlling a users login status? or is it built into rails?

Comment: `session` is sort of like `params`, except it persists for multiple requests. You can use it to store any sort of persistent parameter unique to your individual users (until their session expires or they log out). You can read more about it here: [ActionController: Accessing the Session](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#accessing-the-session)