# Can I use CanCan with model(s) other than User?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, models, cancan

I'm new to rails and building app from data on an api, I have two tables I want to use for users - `students` and `educators`.

I can authenticate in the controllers with

```
private

def fetch_user_data(username, password)

    require 'URI'

    uri = URI('the url for the api')
    res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'username' => username, 'password' => password)
    xml = res.body
    doc = Nokogiri::Slop(xml)

    @status = doc.auth.status.content.to_s
    @username = doc.auth.username.content.to_s
    @token = doc.auth.token.content.to_s
    @person_id = doc.auth.person_pk.content.to_i
    @security_roles = doc.auth.security_roles.content.to_s.downcase
end

def assign_user

    if /faculty/ =~ @security_roles
        @user = Educator.find_by(person_id: @person_id)
    elsif /student/ =~ @security_roles
        @user = Student.find_by(person_id: @person_id)
    end
end

def authenticate_user(username, password)

    fetch_user_data(username, password)
    assign_user
    session[:user_id] = @user.id 
    redirect_to @user 
end
```

Now I know it's probably not pretty, but I'm learning as I go. I use the `authenticate_user()` in the sessions controller, and based on the redirect, the authentication seems fine. I do have one question about the `:user_id` key in the session -- is that a key only created for the session or is it trying to pull a value from a user table? Knowing that would help. My guess is it's just created for the session, but I have no idea.

Ok so now for my real problem. I'm trying to use cancan and I'm getting stuck at defining current user.

I figured I could have the `@current_user` instance point to the `@user` I assigned in `assign_user`. This doesn't seem to be working though. I tried a couple things, but I'm stuck. Maybe I can't even do that? Larger question? Do I have to have a user model to make cancan work? Can I use the two models Educators and Students and mask the user references in cancan on those?

I tried this, but it's not working -- any help?

```
def current_user
    @current_user ||= @user
end
```

**edit:** Figured out a bit. 
1. methods were in `ApplicationHelper`. Moved `current_user()` to `ApplicationController` . Changed syntax to conventional, but added conditionals.

```
def current_user
 if Student.where(id:session[:user_id]).count == 0
     @current_user ||= Educator.find(session[:user_id])
 else
     @current_user ||= Student.find(session[:user_id])
 end
end
```

This seems to fix things, and allows me to use both tables as the user models.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to define current_user (if you aren't using Devise), but this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719958/rails-where-does-the-infamous-current-user-come-from) is pretty standard:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
  end
end
```

As for your question about the session, the way you have it set up, you're setting session[:user_id] equal to @user.id (which is always the same for each user).

Comment: No problem. Do upvote/accept this answer if it helped to resolve your issue. Cheers.

Comment: You should add `return unless session[:user_id]` before trying to set `@current_user`. Without that, every `if current_user` check while signed out will trigger another database query

Answer (score 0):

minor aside consider using the gem CanCanCan which is as it sounds.  CanCan not maintained and some one set up replacement CanCanCan.  You won'thave to change any code.