# Photo is not getting uploaded in database from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I checkedd code was right but i am not able to detect the problem why the photo is not getting uploaded in the database.

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @photo = Photo.new
end 

  def create
    debugger
    @photo = Photo.new(photo_params)
    if @photo.save
     render "show", :notice=> "photo created"
   else   
     render "index", :notice=> "photo could'nt be saved"  
   end

  end
def photo_params
   params.require(:photo).permit(:image)
 end
 end
```

my view for the photo#new is as following

```
 <%= form_for :photo , :url=>{:action=>'create'},:html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
 <%= f.file_field :image %>
 <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

here is my photo model

```
 class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :comments
   has_many :photos_tags
   has_many :tags,  through: :photos_tags
   has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
   validates :user, presence:true
   validates_associated :user
   validates_attachment_presence :image
   validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  end
```

Thanx in advance for the help..

Comment: Can you post the `server log` generated?

Comment: @pavan  there is no serverlog actualy..i checked my database. Its empy

Comment: @RichPeck   I added this to check whether the current point of execution (photo_params ) was able to have any value
and it has parameters of photo

Comment: There should be some log generated.Try to find it.

Comment: Result of " if @photo.save "  led the execution for else condition ..that clearly means that its not been saved

Comment: Try giving `if @photo.save!` instead of `if @photo.save` and tell me if it gives any errors.

Comment: @Pavan it this one : Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c20140804-9115-420r5c20140804-9115-tmcw50'
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c20140804-9115-m8a6vj.jpg'
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 1  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered photos/index.html.erb within layouts/application (13.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 239ms (Views: 64.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)

Comment: Include your photo model and whatever code handles the storing of files. Do you use a gem for uploads?

Comment: yes it gave error "Validation failed: User can't be blank" after i changed to  if @photo.save!

Comment: Hmm,Please post your `Photo` model with the validations.

Comment: class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :comments

  has_many :photos_tags

  has_many :tags,  through: :photos_tags

  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"

  validates :user, presence:true

  validates_associated :user

  validates_attachment_presence :image

  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end

Comment: I meant update your question with `Photo` model.

Comment: Why you are having `validates :user, presence:true` if your `form` doesn't contain a field input for the field `user`? You have to remove it in order to get it work.

Comment: I want to include the user also for the upload I am validating user object, an another model coz every photo is associated with user

Comment: You have this `validates_associated :user` which does that.But you have to remove `validates :user, presence:true`.

Comment: this would violate my associations and validation as per rspec 

both type of validations have their different purposes

Comment: Sounds like you need a hidden field in your form to set the photo's user_id.

Answer (score 0):

The `belongs_to` relation in your model generates a `user_id` column in your photo table, the error you're getting, "User can't be blank", should come from this, as I don't see where you relate the photo to the uploading user.

If you have a `current_user` helper (already there if you're using devise, if not, you might want to set it up, you could look up this SO answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12719996/2726340 ), you might do this :

```
def create
    @photo = Photo.new(photo_params)

    @photo.user = current_user 
    #it should populate the user_id column accordingly if current_user is a User object

    if @photo.save
     render "show", :notice=> "photo created"
   else   
     render "index", :notice=> "photo could'nt be saved"  
   end
end
```

There might be another way, but I think this one is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Great ! Remember to mark this post as the answer to close this question.