# Ruby on Rails - How can I allow users to update there account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am making a notebook application for my school and was wondering if there is anyway that I can allow users who are signed into the application to update there account email, password, first name, last name? I am making my own authentication using `rails g scaffold Users first_name last_name email password:digest` and then `rails g controller sessions new create destroy` to create the login form. But I cannot seem to figure out how to allow the currently signed in user to only edit **their** account information. I have been trying for about 5 days to try to figure this out but I can still not figure it out.

I hope that someone can help me out.

Here is the YouTube video that I got most of this from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQJtlvlNunw

Answer (score 0):

When a user is signed in, information about that user is stored in the `session` hash.  Depending on what you use for authentication, you may have access to a variable called `current_user`, or you may have to define it yourself.

Once you have access to the currently signed-in user, however you choose to implement that, you can only allow updates to user accounts where the `id` matches `current_user.id`.  Of course, you'll probably want some level of authorization logic that allows for certain accounts to have administrator privileges that allow them to update any account, but that's a separate issue.

See this: [Rails: where does the infamous "current_user" come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719958/rails-where-does-the-infamous-current-user-come-from)

Comment: @Alex Sure thing, I hope it was useful to you in some way!

Answer (score 0):

If you have already setup your `user` related model and controller, then you should be able to have a view `app/views/users/edit.html.erb` like this:

```
<h1>Update your profile</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div>
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name%>

        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email%>

        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password%>

        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation%>

        <%= f.submit "Save changes"%>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And, in your `users_controller.rb` you can have `edit` and `update` methods like this:

```
  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Then, when an user submits the form with edited information, it will invoke the `update` action of the user and will update the user information.

Also, to make sure, the user is logged in, you can have a `before_action` in your `users_controller.rb`:

```
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

and you can put `logged_in_user` method inside the `app/controller/application_controller.rb`:

```
# Confirms a logged-in user.
def logged_in_user
  unless logged_in?
    flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
    redirect_to login_url
  end
end
```

Also, if you are not sure where to put `logged_in?` method, you can put it and other user login/logout related methods inside `app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb`:

```
  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end
```

And, finally, don't forget to `include SessionsHelper` inside your `application_controller.rb` to make those user login/logout related helper methods available inside your controllers.

Comment: If it helped you solved your problem. Consider accepting the answer. To learn more about it, see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I can allow users to edit there password but they also see other users passwords too