# Disallow action item with condition in AdminUser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

first question here, I hope to be specific and not stupid.
I'm new also in Rails and AdminUser and I would like to create a controller that show a menu item only if the current_user is of a certain type (in my case: Lektor).

I've written something like this:

```
  disallowed_actions = []
  disallowed_actions << :create if proc {current_admin_user.departments.to_a[0].name != "Lektor" }
  actions :all, :except => disallowed_actions
```

But it doesn't work, and I think it's because the current_admin_user I refer to in proc is not the same of the controller, but I also can't refer to the current_admin_user outside a method or a proc.
Any suggestions?

Comment: How/where is current_admin_user defined? Are you using something like Devise to handle authentication or have you defined your own?

Comment: Actually current_admin_user is from activeadmin and I've not built up on my own the authentication/departments system because I'm working on a project I received from others programmers (which are naturally not reachable any more).

Comment: Where are you putting the above code, could you provide more context?

Answer (score 0):

Create a migration, run: `rails g migration AddRoleToUsers role:string` to add a role to your users.

Migrate `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

In your rails c run `User.first.update_attributes(:role => 'admin')` this will add an 'admin' role to the first user in the db.

In your User model (user.rb) create this method:

```
def admin?
  role == 'admin'
end
```

Now in the view (assuming you're using erb) that you want to hide the action from the normal users add this:

```
<% if current_user.admin? %>
  # show stuff
<% end %>
```

***Note:*** current_user is devise method, if you're not using devise, you need to roll your own method to check for the current signed in user, you can do that with sessions.

*See [Rails: where does the infamous "current_user" come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719958/rails-where-does-the-infamous-current-user-come-from)*

In that way you can hide stuff to the user that is not an admin.

Comment: Thank you, that would be a good solution (I already have department instead of role), but my problem is to hide a menu items button, which I don't explicitly show in the view. So I (think I) can't just hide the button with erb (that's my problem and why I'd like to disallow the action from the controller).

Comment: Oh ok, department should work as well it's just a name. Well, if you want to disable the controller action, use authorization, I recommend you Pundit https://github.com/elabs/pundit . It's very good, and with that you can authorize your controller actions based on your user department, etc. You can also authorize in views so you get the best out of two worlds (authorization in controller actions and in views).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't find it useful. It leads to the same problem I had before: I can't address to the current_user from outside a method in the controller. Or if there's a way, I simply don't know it.